# CodeNarc rule violation for constants

Tags: groovy, constants, rule, codenarc

```
[SRC]final String DATE_PATTERN_FOR_DIRECTORIES = "yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss"
[MSG]The property name DATE_PATTERN_FOR_DIRECTORIES in class UploadTask does not match the pattern [a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

I have a constant **DATE_PATTERN_FOR_DIRECTORIES** which CodeNarc rule I have to exclude to pass the name check or how to name it. When I declare constat it has to be with Upercase letters.

Comment: I assume if you make it static as well, the violation goes away?

Comment: Yes, you are right, tim. That makes the violation to go away.

Comment: I'd argue that codenarc is right then, and they should be private final statics ;-)